# Flutter How to keep pagestate

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have an app and It is listing my Firebase fields with StreamBuilder.

I have BottomNavigationBar in my RootPage. Here is fragment of RootPage's code:

```
int currentTab = 0;
  final List<Widget> screens = [
    const HomePage(
      key: PageStorageKey<String>('key_anasayfa'),
    ),
   const MapPage2(
      key: PageStorageKey<String>('key_mappage'),
    ), 

  ];
  final PageStorageBucket _bucket = PageStorageBucket();
```

Also I have simple BottomNavigationBar and here is my Scaffold's body.

```
...
 body: PageStorage(
          child: screens[currentTab],
          bucket: _bucket,
        ),
```

Here is my HomePage's Scaffold's body:

```
SingleChildScrollView(

          child: Column(
            children: [  
              const Divider(thickness: 1),
              //const CardStackTree(),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              StreamYukWidget(
                yukLimit: limitYuk,
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

That's it. At this point my problem is beginning. StreamBuilder is working but when I click the BottomNavBarItem and again click my HomePage, StreamBuilder refreshing itself. I can't keep my pages alive.
I tried AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin (following docs.) but it doesn't keep anything. Is it because of StreamBuilder?

Comment: watch this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3v4ZofYsn5I  , enable english sub, basically you could use stack or indexedStack, if you use bottom nav bar it will recreate your widget every time you click on a different page

Comment: Well but, using stack or indexedStack good for performance? How it works for streambuilder or widget tree?

Comment: it doesn't matter if you use streambuilder, If you keep the widget state using stack or indexedStack, you will have more info in memory, if you are worried about that, keep using bottom nav bar.

Comment: Thank you sir. It helped me.